# Dynamic VLAN assignment

Tags: switch

I have a Juniper SRX550 router.  Port 0/0/0 is Internet.  0/0/2 is 172.16.64.1/18, and 0/0/3 is 172.16.128.1/18.  I also have the Juniper to do DHCP for the two networks.

Cable goes from 0/0/2 to port 1 on a Netgear ProSafe XS716T (172.16.64.2/18).  Then 0/0/3 to port 1 another Netgear ProSafe XS728T (172.16.128.2/18).  Then, I have a third Netgear switch (172.16.64.3/18) that trunks with the other .64 switch.  All 3 switches are on VLAN 1.

What I'm trying to do is, when a user connects to the 172.16.64.3/18 switch, I want them to get a 172.16.64.0/18 or 172.16.128.0/18 DHCP address depending on their login credentials.  Is this possible?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Network Engineering!  The short answer is yes, if you implement 802.1x, which the Netgear switches do support.  In brief, you will need a RADIUS server that will assign a VLAN based on the users' credentials.  It's not a simple feature, but we can talk more about it if you provide some details.

Comment: Thank you.  I do have a RADIUS server (laptop) which have freeRADIUS.net installed.  I haven't created any accounts yet.  Do I need to implement 802.1x on all 3 Netgear switches or just the one switch 172.16.64.3/18?

Comment: 802.1X is port-based authentication, so you'll need to configure it on all switches that you want to authenticate ports on.

Comment: Just the switch(es) the users connect to.  But a laptop is not a suitable server.  You want it to be as reliable as your infrastructure.

Comment: The users will be connecting to all 3 switches, but I only want the 172.16.64.3/18 to give either a 172.16.64.0/18 or 172.16.128.0/18 ip address.  So I'm assuming I only need to do this only on this one switch.  I'm just using the laptop to test RADIUS, if this works, I'll use something more reliable.

Comment: Should I start by creating 2 VLANS on the 172.16.64.3/18 switch?  VLAN IDs 64 and 128 under Switching--->VLAN?

Comment: That needs to be done, but I would work on getting the Radius server connected to your credential store, like AD, first.

Comment: Do I have to use AD for RADIUS?  I was going to save the user credentials locally on the laptop running RADIUS.

Comment: I like to avoid AD if possible

Comment: No, that's fine.  I just made an assumption you'd use it for single sign-on.

Comment: Ok. I’ll create some test users in RADIUS then create VLAN

Comment: I created some test accounts for RADIUS and created VLANs 64 and 128 in the 172.16.64.3/18 switch. Can you tell me what the next steps are please?

Comment: I had to reset my switch to factory. For some reason, it's not taking "password" for password.  I didn't change it.

Comment: So, I rest my switch, and I'm able to ping it 172.16.64.3, but after setting up a RADIUS server, it won't take "password" for password.

Comment: May be I need to select RADIUS, Local, None for the authentication list.

Comment: ok using 1)RADIUS 2)Local worked.  I'm able to login to the switch now after a delay.

Comment: I still could use your help with the rest of the stuff.

Comment: I’ve never configured these switches before, so I would have to read the manual just like you.  Why don’t you give it a try and I’ll help if you get stuck.

Comment: I'm actually chatting with Netgear support.  They're saying my switch won't work and I need a layer 3 switch.